# Importing list of strings to a Python file containing undeclared variables

Tags: python, variables, import, undefined

I want to know if it is possible to declare or define values (containing undeclared variables) on one python script, and then use them on a second script with local variables.
For example:

On script PARAMETERS.py

```
QUERY_STRING = "SELECT * FROM " + table
```

On script RUN.py

```
import PARAMETERS.py
table = "myTable"
db.execute(PARAMETERS.QUERY_STRING)
```

Naturally I am ommiting several lines, but I am only illustrating what I am wanting to do. Thank you.

Comment: look at string templating: `"SELECT * FROM {table_name}"`

Comment: ``import`` expects the name to be the file name up to and *excluding* the file extension.  ``import PARAMETERS`` not ``import PARAMETERS.py``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

What you are attempting to do is a `NameError` in Python.  However, what you CAN do is define a number of formatting strings, and do the formatting in your script.

in CONFIG.py

```
FOO = 'SELECT * FROM {table}'
```

in DOIT.py

```
import CONFIG
...
table = 'BAR'
db.execute(CONFIG.FOO.format(table=table))
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer yes (Althought I have to say i can't see why you want to do that) you can import parameters from another module just like you did but like that:

if you have `PARAMETERS.py` file in the current folder.

```
from PARAMETERS import QUERY_STRING
```

and then use it at you code, the problem is that **you can't use a parameter for the table name in the execute method**, you will have to use:

```
db.execute("SELECT * FROM myTable")
```

Comment: So the answer is no. In my long script I have multiple queries. And I dont want to scroll all the script to make some changes on these query lines (Reduce the risk of someone accidentely changing the code), and just open the parameters script to modify the queries. But those queries are built with variables declared and used in the main script.

Comment: @Andres you asked if it's possible to declare a variable at one script and then use it in another script - for that question the answer is **yes**. Since i saw why you want to do with that i also included that for SQL execute it's not an option to use variables so that you won't wast your time.

Comment: Thank your for the reply. But that was not my question. My question was if it is possible to define a string with Undeclared variables (table), and use them in the script that has declared such variables, not to declare in one and use it in another. The same script that declares the variable uses it. Regardless the SQL execute function. Lets say: a new variable newString = PARAMETER.QUERY_STRING